# How to get the answer by simultaneous equations in R

Tags: r

I got the answer “x” by following program. And then, I’d like to get the same answer by simultaneous equations in R. How can I get it? Please give me some advice.

```
p<-0.1
p0<-0.05
(x<-((qnorm(0.9)*sqrt(p*(1-p))+qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(p0*(1-p0)))/(p-p0))**2)
#[1] 263.4971

# As simultaneous equations    
# p=0.1
# p0=0.05
# y=0.1-qnorm(0.9)*sqrt(p*(1-p)/x)
# y=0.05+qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(p0*(1-p0)/x)
# I want to get x=263.4971.
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: are you trying to say "systems of equations?" `p <- quote({p=0.1; p0=0.05; y=0.1-qnorm(0.9)*sqrt(p*(1-p)/x); 0.05+qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(p0*(1-p0)/x)}); uniroot(function(x) eval(p) - y, c(0, 1e7))$root`

Comment: Wow, very helpful. I got the same answer. Thank you very much for your comment!